# Martian Names for the Year and Month Time Units

Tags: mars, time, unit-systems

A Martian day unit is called a Sol.
A week is supposedly still 7 days/sols.
Have there been any (real or fictional) suggestions for new names for other time units like the Martian year?

How about the significantly less well defined Martian month?

In the Red Mars trilogy, KSR uses 24 months with the same earthly names and approximate lengths but each duplicated twice with a 1 and 2 appended to the name. But they are still called months.

Comment: There are two Martian moons, Phobos and Deimos. The periods are 7 hours 40 minutes and 30 hours 19 minutes. A sol is 24 hours, 39 minutes. Not very useful to define a Martian month.

Comment: Yes. And that assumes lunar related months (which are probably the origin of the earth months).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of popular methods. One is the [Darian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darian_calendar), which has 24 months of 27-28 sols, with month names based on constellations. More of them are discussed in the [Martian Timekeeping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timekeeping_on_Mars#Martian_calendars_in_science) article.

The "[Official](http://www-mars.lmd.jussieu.fr/mars/time/martian_time.html)" means is the angle from Solar Angle 0 crossing, measured 0-360, which can tell the season and other items.